# Android, Separating Activity from its layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created an android library project which contains `activities`

From the base library project i'm going to create many different applications all derived from that base library

The main differences will be the layouts of the `activities` and some `activity-ui` features

My question is how can i separate the activity from it's view.

i will explain:

i have several activities in the library with some controls and logic etc..

now from my derived app i want to inject my own layout to the library activity
in the new layout there is a new button and i want to add some ui logic like popup an alert dialog for example..

what's the best way to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: You are not so clear what do u want ?

Comment: I want the Activity to be on the library project and from the Android application i want to call the library activity but set my own View

Comment: According to you what is Libraray , a JAVA library  ..?

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   MainView view = new MainView(this);
    setContentView(view);


}
```

Inside the class MainView

```
public MainView(@NonNull Activity activity) {
        super(activity);
        View view = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.activity_main, this);
}
```

Now we are using a view to find the rest of the view